# Date issues in jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi i done date format in jquery ajax. i got the value from database and i converted the dateformat as dd-MM-YYYY. now the problem is, **i m getting the previous month**. Ex:database value is 2015-04-02, after converting dateformat i got 02-03-2015. Kindly help me. My coding is.

```
var pcd_date = new Date(data.pcd_date),
yr = pcd_date.getFullYear(),
month = +pcd_date.getMonth() < 10 ? '0' + pcd_date.getMonth() : pcd_date.getMonth() ,
day = +pcd_date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + pcd_date.getDate() : pcd_date.getDate(),
pcddate = day + '-' + month + '-' + yr;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gives a result between 0 and 11.

From [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) :

> The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.

You should **add 1 to getMonth()** to have it from 1 to 12 as follow :

```
var pcd_date = new Date(data.pcd_date),
yr = pcd_date.getFullYear(),
month = +(pcd_date.getMonth() +1 ) < 10 ? '0' + (pcd_date.getMonth() +1 ) : (pcd_date.getMonth() +1 ),
day = +pcd_date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + pcd_date.getDate() : pcd_date.getDate(),
pcddate = day + '-' + month + '-' + yr;
```

or doing it one time :

```
var pcd_date = new Date(data.pcd_date),
yr = pcd_date.getFullYear(),
m = pcd_date.getMonth() +1,
month = +m < 10 ? '0' + m : m,
day = +pcd_date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + pcd_date.getDate() : pcd_date.getDate(),
pcddate = day + '-' + month + '-' + yr;
```

Answer (score 2):

because [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) return 0 based value

> The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date
>   according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates
>   the first month of the year).

```
var pcd_date = new Date(data.pcd_date),
    yr = pcd_date.getFullYear(),
    month = pcd_date.getMonth() + 1,
    day = +pcd_date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + pcd_date.getDate() : pcd_date.getDate();
month = month < 10 ? '0' + month : month
var pcddate = day + '-' + month + '-' + yr;
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, January is represented by 0, December by 11. You need to add 1 to the value returned by `getMonth`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code for:

```
pcd_date.getMonth()
```

to

```
pcd_date.getMonth() + 1
```

Because the getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

Answer (score 0):

function `getMonth()` will return the range between 0-11

You need add one before saving.